# Snowflake External Stage: Refreshing Azure Credentials?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

We have an application where each customer is provisioned an Azure Blob container from which Snowflake periodically copies data using an external stage(we create an external stage per customer). When setting up an external stage for the customer's container, we use the Azure SAS token:

```
CREATE STAGE db.public.cust_1_ext_stage url = 'azure://cust_container.blob.core.windows.net/data-copy' credentials =(
        azure_sas_token = 'sas_token_for_customer'
    ) file_format = (type = JSON, compression = GZIP);
```

The problem is that the SAS is set to expire every 7 days. So a few questions:

1. Does Snowflake have a way to refresh SAS tokens? Couldn't find anything in the docs.
2. If `1)` is not possible, Is there a way to get the expiration of the SAS token in Snowflake via some query so we can have some application logic to update the creds? I tried `SHOW STAGES;` query which only tells me that a credential is present but no other info.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use [STORAGE INTEGRATION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html)? From doc: "We highly recommend this option, which avoids the need to supply a SAS token when creating stages or loading data."

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yes, I don't own/control Azure storage. I only have access to customer containers via SAS which is also what I am using for Snowflake data loading.

Comment: @HeloWorld Assuming you know the SAS token you could use `ALTER STAGE <stage_name> SET CREDENTIALS = ( AZURE_SAS_TOKEN = 'string' )`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yep, I know this is possible. My second question was around knowing _when_. If Snowflake can tell me when a SAS is set to expire, I can have some application job run the query you mention. That is of course without me explicitly maintaining the expiration in some table some where.